# GIT over SSH in Ansible hangs, eventhough ssh-agent forwarding is set up

Tags: git, ssh, timeout, ansible, ssh-agent

I have set up everyhing I could find, but still cloning a repo from GitHub hangs the provisioning process.

I have:

- server in known_hosts
- .ssh/config

  ```
  Host github.com
    ForwardAgent yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
  ```
- copied private key
- public key is in authorized_keys
- the command runs as `vagrant` user
- the play is:

  ```
  - name: Checkout from git
    git: repo=git@github.com:username/repositoryname.git dest=/srv/website
  ```

Comment: Make sure you're not running this task with `sudo`, because it breaks agent forwarding.

Comment: @techtonik even if the forwarding is set for the root user?

Comment: @cvsguimaraes forwarding is a chain from your `ssh-agent` port to remote SSH port, and going through `sudo` breaks this chain unless you work around this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24134109/239247

Answer (score 61):

Just to expand on tillda's answer, that config can be placed in an ansible.cfg file alongside your playbook. e.g.:

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

I'd say it's better to do that than setting as an env variable, as placing it in a conf file is both more declarative and also will minimise the steps needed for other people you may be working with to going with a project.

Conf docs:
http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#the-ansible-configuration-file

Example config file:
https://raw.github.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg

Answer (score 14):

I want to share the answer that worked for me:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/u6o-sWynMjo/69UwJfJPq7cJ - From Ansible Google Group

> For ansible,  ssh-add to load ssh keys in your host machine first.
> Then use "ssh" as connection type with forwarding enabled.
>
> Such as:
>
> ```
> $ ssh-add  
> $ export ANSIBLE_TRANSPORT="ssh"  
> $ export  ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS="-o ForwardAgent=yes"
> ```
>
> See manual for ssh-add for running the agent.

The Ansible docs for `ssh-args` are http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#ssh-args

Answer (score 7):

this works for me

```
- name: ensure known hosts
  shell: touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- name: remove github.com from known host
  shell: ssh-keygen -R github.com
  # >> instead of > to keep existing known_hosts file
- name: ensure github.com in known host
  shell: ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: no need as git ansible module has a flag accept_hostkey to ensure it. Just turn it on.

Comment: A module for Ansible to maintain the /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts file https://github.com/bfmartin/ansible-sshknownhosts

Answer (score 1):

Add to ansible.cfg the following parameter:

```
[defaults]
sudo_flags=-HE
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was the repository string. I had a bitbucket private repository set as:

git@tsrs...

but it should be:

***ssh***://git@tsrs...

Notice the subtle absence of the prefix "ssh". The weird part is that if I clone a github repository without the "ssh", it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had an error :

> *bitbucket.org has an unknown hostkey. Set accept_hostkey to True or manually add the hostkey prior to running the git module*

I had to add a `accept_hostkey` parameter to my git module command :

playbook :

```
tasks:
    - name: clone
      git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:robusta-code/xyz.git
           dest=/app
           accept_hostkey=yes
```

ansible.cfg

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```