# How do you give a Newly Provisioned Server access to a Private Git Repo with Ansible?

Tags: git, ssh, ansible

I have provisioned a server with `ansibl`e and now I would like to clone a `private git repo` (not `github`).

So my `local machine's ssh key` is authorized on the `private git repo` and what I have done up till now is `copy` my local public and private ssh key to the server.

But I feel this is not the best way to go about it.

I know if you are using `github` you can use the `API` to create a deploy key. But I am not.

So the only other way I can see is:

1. Generate ssh key-pair on new server
2. Copy that newly created ssh key-pair locally with `fetch`
3. `ssh-copy-id` or use `authorized_keys` to add the servers key to the private git repo

Is there something I am missing, can it be done in another easier way?

Comment: "Is there something I am missing, can it be done in another easier way?" - You mean besides using ansible to automate the 3 steps you describe (ssh-keygen, copy pubkey locally, append pubkey to private git's `authorized_keys`) and run it as a playbook?

Comment: What, exactly, do you think is wrong with those described steps?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't described what your constraints are, and haven't mentioned if you're comfortable creating additional keys and managing them within your private git repo.

Another possible option:

4. Setup `ssh-agent` and add your personal key to it before running ansible, and forward your agent to the remote host when you run ansible.

For that solution: [SSH Agent Forwarding with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible) for more details.

Comment: Well I'm looking for a best practise, though that kind of thing is frowned upon here

Comment: What's wrong with adding a `deploy` key with readonly permissions in your `private git repo`, and placing that on the remote server?