# Ansible Task Clone Private Repo Hangs

Tags: laravel, github, ansible

Set up a repo to set up a Laravel server. A provisioning script using Ansible basically.The repo is called [Stedding](https://github.com/jasperf/stedding). It is based on a [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-basic-php-application-using-ansible-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-updating-environment-variables) and some code from [Roots Trellis](https://github.com/roots/trellis) as I need PHP 7.1 packages.

Now the issue is that the private Github repo does not get cloned. Been reading on ssh agents, forwarding and all that. Tried sudoers and ansible.cfg setups like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible). But no success yet. I prefer not to add private keys.
So I tried what Geerlingguy suggested [here](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/cloning-private-github-repositories-ansible-on-remote-server-through-ssh#comment-5881) using

```
Host [server-address-here] [ip-address-here]
    ForwardAgent yes
```

inside `~./ssh/config` . I also added:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes
```

to ansible.cfg. This to do proper forwarding and avoiding adding private ssh keys. But as `/var/www/` is 0700 `www-data:www-data` I cannot turn off `become` to become `sudo` and get it done as there then will not be enough permissions:

```
"msg": "Could not open /var/www, [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www'", 
    "rc": 13
```

And this he mentioned was needed to make the forwarding work.

Main code snippet loading cloning task is:

```
- name: create /var/www/ directory
    file: dest=/var/www/ state=directory owner=www-data group=www-data mode=0700

  - name: Clone git repository
    git:
      repo: "{{ repo_url }}"
      dest: /var/www/laravel
      version: master
      update: no
      accept_hostkey: yes
    become: yes
    become_user: www-data
    register: cloned
```

With the current setup it all hangs at:

```
TASK [Clone git repository] ****************************************************
task path: /Users/jasper/webdesign/stedding/php.yml:39
Using module file /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.2.1.0_2/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/source_control/git.py
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: laravel
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=laravel -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/jasper/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 128.199.35.232 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245="` echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> PUT /var/folders/_4/g8fn6chn46g9v058h8k4pzpw0000gn/T/tmpO09os2 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245/git.py
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=laravel -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/jasper/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]'
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: laravel
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=laravel -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/jasper/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r xxx.xxx.xx.xxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:www-data:r-x /tmp/ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245/ /tmp/ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245/git.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: laravel
<xxx.xxx.xx.xxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=laravel -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/jasper/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt xxx.xxx.xx.xxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S  -p "[sudo via ansible, key=vvqwwyduilnxfbnxgpojunlavpkasofr] password: " -u www-data /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-vvqwwyduilnxfbnxgpojunlavpkasofr; /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1494744537.18-20302566024245/git.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
```

This also happens after I added Github on the server to known hosts using ([Ansible suggestion](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/git_module.html)):

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com > /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

Any idea how I can make the cloning work and keep the directory rights and permissions secure for installing the Laravel app?

Comment: Clone repo as `laravel` user (because only this user has access to your agent's keys) and then make correct ownership with `file` module. Becoming unprevileged user is a tricky thing in Ansible.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. Also realized I did not set AgentForwarding in `~./ssh/config` properly after all. Could not answer my own question just yet. But have updated the repo some more and cloning is working now. Was lucky enough to found a gist that helped me debug and clone properly: https://gist.github.com/pogorelov-ss/41893e17c7c4776d4d57 . Not all done yet as git paths on remote are off, but I passed the frozen stage and got it cloned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the main issue was that I needed to set agent forwarding properly. I did it using

```
Host *
  ForwardAgent yes
```

in `~/.ssh/config`
That and I decided to use root as a user to set up most playbook material. Root does not require switching to sudo. For parts like cloning I could use the user laravel as it had access to the webroot as owner and that worked as well. So no need for sudo there either.

I have not worked out switching to sudo after sudo user has been created by Ansible. Still new to this all. But progress made. And I am sure the host forwarding hint will help many.