# Is it possible to add an ssh key to the agent for a private repo in an ansible playbook?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I am using Ansible to provision a Vagrant environment.  As part of the provisioning process, I need to connect from the currently-provisioning VM to a private external repository using an ssh key in order to use composer to pull in modules for an application.  I've done a lot of reading on this before asking this question, but still can't seem to comprehend what's going on.

What I want to happen is:

1. As part of the playbook, on the Vagrant VM, I add the ssh key to the private repo to the ssh-agent
2. Using that private key, I am then able to use composer to require modules from the external source

I've read articles which highlight specifying the key in playbook execution.  (E.g. `ansible-play -u username --private-key play.yml`) As far as I understand, this isn't for me, as I'm calling the playbook via Vagrant file.  I've also read articles which mention ssh forwarding. ([SSH Agent Forwarding with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible)). Based on what I have read, this is what I've done:

1. On the VM being provisioned, I insert a known_hosts file which consists of the host entries of the machines which house the repos I need:
2. On the VM being provisioned, I have the following in `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host <VM IP>
     ForwardAgent yes
   ```
3. I have the following entries in my ansible.cfg to support ssh forwarding:

   ```
   [defaults]
   transport = ssh

   [ssh_connection]
   ssh_args=-o ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r

   [privilege_escalation]
   pipelining = False
   ```
4. I have also added the following task to the playbook which tries to
   use composer:

   ```
   - name: Add ssh agent line to sudoers
     become: true
     lineinfile:
       dest: /etc/sudoers
       state: present
       regexp: SSH_AUTH_SOCK
       line: Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
   ```
5. I exit the ansible provisioner and add the private key on the provisioned VM to the agent via a shell provisioner  (This is where I suspect I'm going wrong)
6. Then, I attempt to use composer, or call git via the command module.  Like this, for example, to test:

   ```
   - name: Test connection
     command: ssh -T git@github.com
   ```
7. Finally, just in case I wasn't understanding ssh connection forwarding correctly, I assumed that what was supposed to happen was that I needed to first add the key to my **local** machine's agent, then forward that through to the provisioned VM to use to grab the repositories via composer.  So I used `ssh-add` on my local machine before executing `vagrant up` and running the provisioner.

No matter what, though, I always get permission denied when I do this.  I'd greatly appreciate some understanding as to what I may be missing in my understanding of how ssh forwarding should be working here, as well as any guidance for making this connection happen.

Comment: Are you using the `insecure_key` file that Vagrant provides?

Comment: No, I've replaced Vagrant's key with my own key.  That key is different than the one I need to connect to the external repository, however.

Comment: Got it. So, could you send the other key via a template or ansible file module?

Comment: So, that's the thing.  The key is on the server already. (I do it via a template.)  I couldn't figure out how to add the key to the ssh-agent using ansible, so I thought I could add it via a shell provisioner, and then go back to Ansible.  But, I think ansible does stuff in its own shell, so it doesn't know about the key.  If I run composer from the same shell script provisioner, it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain I understand your question correctly, but I often setup machines that connect to a private bitbucket repository in order to clone it. You don't need to (and shouldn't) use agent forwarding for that ("ssh forwarding" is unclear; there's "authentication agent forwarding" and "port forwarding", but you need neither in this case).

Just to be clear with terminology, you are running Ansible in your **local machine**, you are provisioning the **controlled machine**, and you want to ssh from the controlled machine to a **third-party server**.

What I do is I upload the ssh key to the controlled machine, in `/root/.ssh` (more generally `$HOME/.ssh` where `$HOME` is the home directory of the controlled machine user who will connect to the third-party server—in my case that's `root`). I don't use the names `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`, because I don't want to touch the default keys of that user (these might have a different purpose; for example, I use them to backup the controlled machine). So this is the code:

```yaml
- name: Install bitbucket aptiko_ro ssh key
  copy:
    dest: /root/.ssh/aptiko_ro_id_rsa
    mode: 0600
    content: "{{ aptiko_ro_ssh_key }}"

- name: Install bitbucket aptiko_ro ssh public key
  copy:
    dest: /root/.ssh/aptiko_ro_id_rsa.pub
    content: "{{ aptiko_ro_ssh_pub_key }}"
```

Next, you need to tell the controlled machine `ssh` this: "When you connect to the third-party server, use key X instead of the default key, and logon as user Y". You tell it in this way:

```yaml
- name: Install ssh config that uses aptiko_ro keys on bitbucket
  copy:
    dest: /root/.ssh/config
    content: |
      Host bitbucket.org
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aptiko_ro_id_rsa
      User aptiko_ro
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I think you've got my intention spot on.  I'm doing the same thing you are with the ssh key, the piece I was missing was your second step (which you explained beautifully, by the way).  I'll give this a try, report back, and hopefully accept the answer.