# Ansible Become passwordless

Tags: ssh, ansible, inventory

In shell I am following the below approach to become root user without any password. And it is working fine.

```
ssh-agent bash

ssh-add /repository/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa_ansible

ssh -A ansible@e8-df1

[ansible@e8-df1 ~]$ sudo -i
[root@e8-df1 ~]#
```

However, In ansible, I do not achieve the same and getting error. Below is my ansible inventory and playbook.

**Inventory:**

```
[qv]
e8-df1
e8-df2

[qv:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=ansible
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/repository/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa_ansible
```

**Playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: qv
  become: yes
  roles:
    - abc
```

**Error:**

```
fatal: [e8-df1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "setup"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to e8-df1 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
fatal: [e8-df2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "setup"
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to e8-df2 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
```

I have gone through some documents and Q&As and they are suggesting to add below line in the sudoers file.

```
ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now, I am not able to realize why the shell procedure is working without the sudoers configuration. And if there is any other way to achieve the same in the ansible?

Comment: Are you saying that without modifying /etc/sudoers, interactive sudo works but via Ansible does not, but if you do edit /etc/sudoers, both methods work? If so, there is some existing sudoers config which is allowing interactive sudo. Run `egrep -v '^$|^#' /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d/*` which will show you all the effective sudo rules in place.

Comment: I have checked in the /etc/sudoers.d also and there no such rules.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you connect via shell, you are passing the Agent in the SSH connection using the **-A** parameter, in Ansible you need to configure this behavior if you want to pass the agent on SSH connection.

Here a related question with a solution: [SSH Agent Forwarding with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible)

Basically you need to provide on ansible.cfg the SSH parameter that you want, also you can add the parameters to hosts you are connecting, with a configuration of SSH client on ~/.ssh/config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup this `private_key_file = /path/to/file` in configuration file `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

As per you questioned it will should look like as below:

```
private_key_file = /repository/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa_ansible
```

Hope this helps.