# Ansible and git with SSH key forwarding - works, but with two problems to solve

Tags: git, ssh, ansible

I have an Ansible task that checks out a git repo with SSH key forwarding, and it works. But with two problems that I'd like to fix.

First a quick recap of my configuration:

- `ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ForwardAgent=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey'` in my inventory
- `ForwardAgent yes` in `.ssh/config` on the client
- the `ssh-agent` on the client properly loaded with all the relevant keys

(edited to add this point that I at first forgotten to mention)

- the configuration suggested here: [SSH Agent Forwarding with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible)

```
- name: Fix sudoers for git clone
  tags: user
  when: is_linux
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    regexp: '.*SSH_AUTH_SOCK$'
    line: 'Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"'
    validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'
```

(end edit)

The task is straightforward:

```
- name: Clone project repositories
  tags: repos
  # become: true -- this breaks key forwarding
  # become_user: fritz
  git:
    repo: 'git@bitbucket.org:{{ item.user }}/{{ item.name }}'
    dest: '{{ workareas }}/{{ item.folder }}/{{ item.name }}'
    accept_hostkey: yes
    force: no
  with_items: '{{ repositories }}'
```

First problem: it does work, but when I add `become/become_user` key forwarding is no more enabled: the keys installed on the bastion host are tried (and of course this fails).
It is not a big issue for me: without `become` Ansible creates the repo with the wrong ownership, but I fix it in a later task. It's more a thing of understanding how Ansible works.

The second problem is more important. For a number of reasons I have a high number of keys on my client: without a specific configuration the `ssh` client submits them in an unpredictable order and usually I get the server aborting with '`too many authentication failures`'. Putting into `.ssh/config` the specific associations of keys to hosts fixes the problem:

```
Host bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/fritz@Mistral-bitbucket
```

But this only works when running `git` directly from the client; with Ansible it doesn't work, it still tries all the keys. At the moment I'm lucky and the proper key is submitted early, but there's no warranty it will be always like this.

Basically the question is: is it possible to have key forwarding and the `.ssh/config` file enforced also on the bastion host?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... It's more a thing of understanding how Ansible works.

Connect to your remote host manually with `ssh`, then run `sudo -u root ssh-add -l` and you'll see that your agent is inaccessible. This is expected behavior -- environment variables like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` don't transition across privilege escalation boundaries by default (which is exactly the situation when you use `become: true`).

Running `sudo` manually, we can work around this by explicitly preserving the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable. Unlike the previous command, this should work:

```
sudo -u root --preserve-env=SSH_AUTH_SOCK ssh-add -l
```

We can have Ansible run `sudo` with the same options by setting the `become_flags` configuration variable in our `ansible.cfg`:

```
[privilege_escalation]
become_flags = --preserve-env=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

With that configuration in place, we can now successfully run something like:

```
ansible remotehost --become -a 'ssh-add -l'
```

---

> Basically the question is: is it possible to have key forwarding and the `.ssh/config` file enforced also on the bastion host?

If you copy your *public* key to the remote server, you should be able to configure ssh on the remote system using `IdentitiesOnly=yes` and `IdentityFile` so that it will only use those specific keys in the agent.

For example, in `~/.ssh/config` on the *remote* host, you would write:

```
Host github.com
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/my-key.pub
```

Comment: I was reviewing my post to add that I did the configuration suggested here for SSH_AUTH_SOCK - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124140/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-ansible. Now let me review if I did everything you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: For what concerns the SSH_AUTH_SOCK I think I'm starting to understand, or at least I know where to look.

Comment: For what concerns the keys, your suggestion worked. I had to understand two errors of mine, though... Ok, I see it is apparently impossible to post a code chunk here, so I'm going to use 'answer your question' below.

Answer (score 0):

@larsks suggestion for the keys worked. But I had to fix two errors that I was doing:

1. Since there's no `become` the config file to use is under `root`, not under the user home (`fritz` in my case).
2. At this point the tilde expands in the wrong way (again under `root`), so the explicit path to the home root must be used.

Summing up this task prepares things in the proper way.

Thanks to @larsks.

```
- name: Create SSH config file for root
  tags: repos
  copy:
    dest: '/root/.ssh/config'
    content: |
      Host bitbucket.org
      IdentityFile /home/fritz/.ssh/fritz@{{ ansible_hostname|capitalize }}-bitbucket
```